# Join tables with comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Products, 
      ProductDetails 
WHERE Products.ProductID  IN (111,222,333,444,555) 
AND Products.ProductID    =  ProductDetails.ProductID
```

My current SQL is like the above. Now, there is a new requirement, where I want the ProductID from the comma separated list to still be available in the recordset even if it's not found in the Products and ProductDetails tables.

How can I do this? Maybe can achieve that using LEFT JOIN? I am not really good with SQL, hope someone can help with working codes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you should create a **'Table-Values Function'**, which will return you a table based result set from your comma separate string

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcSplit]
(
    @param      NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter  CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @t TABLE (val NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET @param += @delimiter

    ;WITH a AS
    (
        SELECT CAST(1 AS BIGINT) f,
               CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @param) t,
               1 seq
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t + 1,
               CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @param, t + 1),
               seq + 1
        FROM   a
        WHERE  CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @param, t + 1) > 0
    )
    INSERT @t
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@param, f, t - f)         
    FROM   a
           OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

    RETURN
END
```

and use LEFT JOIN, so you will always get result set from your first query, which is your input string, which has product IDs, Below is an example query. *(You don't need to write Stored Procedure, you can just use query, and pass your ProductIds in @str variable.)*

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(MAX)
SET @str='111,222,333,444,555'

SELECT val , p.ProductID, pd.ProductID from dbo.[funcSplit](@str,',')  a
LEFT JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID=a.val
LEFT JOIN ProductDetails pd ON pd.ProductID=a.val
```

You will get output like

```
val p.ProductID pd.ProductID
111 111      NULL
222 222      222
333 333      NULL
444 NULL     NULL
```

Hope this will work!

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this. Doesn't this has to be put in a stored procedure?

Comment: No, you don't need to put in Stored Procedure, you just need to use as query,in @str variable you need to pass your comma separated string. Just create function funcSplit, and than execute query which i posted, it will return you result

Comment: 2 steps, First Create Function (not in procedure). Then try Step 2 code in procedure.

Comment: I have managed to get this to run in SQL Server Management Studio. But, the real code needs to be run in classic ASP page. Any idea how can I do that? How can I do the "DECLARE @str nvarchar(MAX), and SET @str='111,222,333,444,555'", in ASP?

Comment: You don't need to declare variable in MS SQL, you can just use variable in query and pass values from your ASP code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `IN` clause will not help you in this case. You have to provide a table which contains the IDs. One way was introduced already: a UDF which converts a comma separated list into a table.

There is another quite simple way to get what you want:

```
select * 
  from (
         SELECT * FROM (VALUES(111),(222),(333),(444),(555)) as x(ID)
        ) x 
        left join Products on x.ID = Products.ID 
        left join ProductDetails 
          on Products.ProductID = ProductDetails.ProductID
```

This lists all IDs from the list. In case there is a matching `Product` it will list that Product. And in case there are `ProductDetails` for that product, it will list those details.

Comment: Works, but I need to first break up my comma separated list into VALUES(111),(222),(333),(444),(555)... which is a hassle. I will use Suresh's solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that as well. I only wanted to show an alternative.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Formatting the # list appropriately is super simple in Excel. Or if you had to do it programmatically, it would also be simple in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Try Left join,

```
;With CTE as
(
select 111 as a
Union All
select 222
Union All
select 333
Union All
select 444
Union All
select 555
)
Select CTE.*,P.*, PD.*  from CTE
left join Products P on P.ProductID =CTE.a
left join ProductDetails PD 
ON 
    P.ProductID = PD.ProductID 
WHERE 
    CTE.a IN (111,222,333,444,555)
```

Comment: You mean creating a temp table? I am trying to avoid this and avoid using stored procedure if possible.

Comment: Yes, no need to use #temp table. Just try my code, i have changes inner join to left join only.

Comment: Now I got your requirement. Please check, i have updated my code.

Comment: There is a missing dot.. CTE.* - Anyway, it still doesn't work. Still doesn't return 555 in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Left Join should work. I have created sample and executed it is working. It shows all the product even through it is not present in the ProductDetail.

```
 select p.*,pd.* from Product p left join 
 ProductDetails pd  on (p.id = pd.ProductId) where
 p.id in (1,2,3,5)
```

List of Products

[image]

List of Product Details

[image]

And the result of the Query above query is

[image]

Comment: You misunderstood me. I need the result to also return ProductID that is not in Products and not in ProductDetails. For example: where
 p.id in (1,2,3,5,600) - I want 600 to also appear.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below Query.

```
SELECT 
    P.*, PD.* 
FROM 
    Products P inner join ProductDetails PD 
ON 
    P.ProductID = PD.ProductID 
WHERE 
    P.ProductID IN (111,222,333,444,555)
```

Let me know in case you need more details.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Let's assume ProductID 555 doesn't exist in my tables. I want it (555) to still be available in the recordset result. But this SQL doesn't do that, as it only returns 111, 222, 333 and 444.

Comment: He is asking about a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: The query is exact replica of your query mentioned in the question. If 555 is not present in ProductDetails table, then your query won't return recordset for it.

Comment: He was not asking for a left join. He was asking whether the left join would do the job. It does not. But I have to admit, it took me a while to figure out what he was looking for.